# Lifetime of stringstream str and member variable

Tags: c++, address-sanitizer

I get a heap-use-after-free error with ASAN when trying to print a string from a str object created from stringstream stored in a member inside a class:

```
const char* MyClass::somefunction() const throw()
{
   std::stringstream msg;

   // print some stuff into the stringstream

   m_Member = msg.str();
   return m_Member.c_str();
}
```

m_Member is of type mutable std::string  (not a reference).

The return value from somefunction is immediately handed over to some other function that tries to print it. This print attempt causes heap use after free:

```
MyClass object;
printFunction( object.somefunction() );
```

According to ASAN, printFunction tries to access an address that was allocated by the msg.str() call within the stringstream class, then destroyed again withing msg.str() in the basic_string destructor.

Am I making wrong assumptions regarding the lifetime of the object returned by msg.str()?

Edit: Ok, one more detail: MyClass is in fact an exception class and the error occurs while printing the error in the catch block after an exception:

```
try
{
    // throws exception of type MyClass
}
catch ( MyClass& exception)
{
   printFunction( exception.somefunction() );
}
```

m_Member is a member of the exception class.

Comment: Please show a complete program we can compile which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Can you please provide an [mcve] please. The problem probably is in the code that you don't show.

Comment: not answer, but why not return a string?

Comment: @Werner Henze I cannot, this is part of a large project with proprietary code. For now I only want to know if there is an obvious problem.

Comment: If you remove the proprietary code, the error disappears?

Comment: if you cannot create a mcve then the problem is elsewhere

Comment: Does the mutable on the member std::string object change any assumptions about the lifetime of the objects returned by std::string::str or std::string::str::c_str?

Comment: @Desperado17: "*I cannot, this is part of a large project with proprietary code.*" That's what "Minimal" means in [mcve]. It means you cut out your "large project" and reduce it down to the bare minimum that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: ...and if you can't copy existing code because it's "proprietary", you should be able to make an example from scratch.

Comment: Well, the presented code is unproblematic. But there are too many pieces missing to be sure.

Comment: What is the scope of m_Member?  From your code we can't tell if it's local, global, or other.  If it's local than that returned string will be out of scope.

Comment: No, its a member of the class.

Comment: Added some more info to the original post.

Comment: Please, do not *describe* the code and the error message ("m_Member is a member of the exception class.", "According to ASAN, printFunction tries to access ..." ). Instead, provide them **as is, exactly**. If you don't want to show your whole original code (well, we do not want to see your *whole code* too), then **reduce** that code.

Comment: This question has a simple and obvious answer.